# change the Fore color Command button in if condition

Tags: vba

I wanna change the font color of Y & in the below code. Do assist
if i change color in commandbutton properties i applies both to Y and M. I want to have independent color for both

```
If checker = False Then
CommandButton1.Caption = "Y"
checker = True
Else
CommandButton1.Caption = "m"
checker = False
End If
CommandButton1.Enabled = False
```

Comment: What have you tried after doing your research and what problem did you run into?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ForeColor` property. This is a fairly easy thing to look up online. You can also just look at the properties of the button object in the designer.

It makes no difference if it is within an If condition.

```
CommandButton1.ForeColor = vbYellow
```